# Bootstrap Dropdown submenu expands by default

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am going crazy trying to figure what I have done wrong. In my nav, I have a drop down 'Small Groups' and then within that drop down, there is the resources nav item which has a submenu dropdown. When I hover over Small Groups the resources dropdown is open too. I only want the resources one to open when I actually click on resources or hover on resources. What am I doing wrong here?

Side Note: This is my first time building a bootstrap nav menu inside of PHP statements like this so that may be what is throwing me off.

My markup and PHP is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


    <?php
    //Check if logged in
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin']) {


        //They are logged in
        echo '<li><a href="userDashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="videopage.php">Videos</a></li>';
        echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Small Groups</a>'
        . '<ul id="smallGroupsSubMenu" class="dropdown-menu">';
        if (!$smallGroupsAdmin) {
            echo '<li><a href="subscription.php?smallGroupsSignup">Sign up</a></li>';
            echo '<li><a href="">Overview</a></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li><a href="">Leader’s Guide(start here)</a></li>';
        }

        //if logged in AND have bought small groups
        if ($smallGroupsAdmin) {
            echo '
                <li><a href="smallGroupVids.php">Videos</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Resources</a> 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="LeadersGuide.pdf">Leader’s Guide</a></li>
                        <li><a href="DiscussionQuestionsforSGM.pdf">Discussion Questions for SGM</a></li>
                        <li><a href="DiscussionQuestionsforFF.pdf">Discussion Questions for FF</a></li>
                        <li><a href="FASTERScaleCheck-ins.pdf">FASTER scale Check-ins</a></li>
                        <li><a href="GroupCheckin&CC.pdf">Group Check-in & CC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="FasterScalePrintable.pdf">FASTER scale printable</a></li>
                        <li><a href="FASTERscaleQ&AwithExperts.pdf">FASTER scale Q&A with Experts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="CommonDoubleBinds.pdf">Common Double Binds</a></li>
                        <li><a href="The59OneAnothers.pdf">The 59 One Another’s</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                ';
        }
        echo '
                                            ';
        //if logged in AND have NOT bought small groups
        if (!$smallGroupsAdmin) {
            echo '
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Resources</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Leader’s Guide</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Discussion Questions for SGM</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Discussion Questions for FF</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">FASTER scale Check-ins</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Group Check-in & CC</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">FASTER scale printable</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">FASTER scale Q&A with Experts</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Common Double Binds</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">The 59 One Another’s</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                ';
        }

        //if logged in AND have bought small groups
        if ($smallGroupsAdmin) {
            echo '<li><a href="smallGroupVids.php">Videos</a></li>';
        }

        //if logged in AND have signed up for the FASTER tool (this would naturally include those who are admins)
        if ($smallGroupsMember) {
            echo '<li><a href="weeklyCheckIn.php">Weekly Check-in</a></li>';
        }

        //if logged in
        echo '</ul>';

        echo ' </li>';

        echo '<li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="https://secure-q.net/Donations/StudentMI/10836">Donate</a></li>';
        if ($isAdmin) {
            echo '<li><a href="admin.php">Admin Panel</a></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li><a href="#">Hi, ' . $_SESSION['userinfo']['fname'] . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '<li><a class="logOut" href="login.php?logout">LogOut</a></li>';
    } else {
        //If the user is NOT logged in
        echo '<li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="#">Small Groups</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="subscription.php?smallGroupsSignup">Sign up</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Overview</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Resources</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Leader’s Guide</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Discussion Questions for SGM</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Discussion Questions for FF</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">FASTER scale Check-ins</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Group Check-in & CC</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">FASTER scale printable</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">FASTER scale Q&A with Experts</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">Common Double Binds</span></li>
                        <li><span class="menuLink">The 59 One Another’s</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </li>';
        echo '<li><a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="https://secure-q.net/Donations/StudentMI/10836">Donate</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a class="signUp" href="login.php?signup">Sign Up</a></li>';
    }

    ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the rendered HTML, and any CSS or JS? Add it as a snippet to your post so that we have a [mcve]